# When do I use the "when" keyword (or expression) in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, operator-keyword

I'm in the process of learning how to extend my local GNU emacs software by learning emacs lisp. In one of the source codes I encountered I saw a "when" there. I think this is a control structure but I'm not sure. I've tried googling "the when keyword/expression in emacs lisp" (and other similar permutations of the sort). I even checked the gnu.org website. I only found source codes that contained "when" but no description for how and and when to use "when". Can someone tell me how and in what appropriate situations should I use "when" in control structures, etc, in emacs lisp? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type <kbd>C-h f when RET</kbd> and you'll see the documentation:

> `when` is a Lisp macro in `subr.el`.
>
> `(when COND BODY...)`
>
> When `COND` yields non-`nil`, eval `BODY` forms sequentially and return value of last one, or `nil` if there are none.

You can see how it's implemented if you macro-expand it:

```
ELISP> (macroexpand '(when cond body1 body2 body3))
(if cond
    (progn body1 body2 body3))
```

You should use `when` instead of `if` in the case where you don't have an "else" clause. It looks nicer, and it provides a hint to the reader that there's no "else" clause. If you have an "else" clause but no "then" clause you can write `unless`.

Comment: And also note that there's an `unless`, which may be preferable to `(when (not ...) ...)`

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer!

Comment: Seems the link is broken, https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhenToUseIf though works. This seems to indicate this answer is wrong. Use `when` when you want to indicate side effects.

Answer (score 4):

Many people follow the convention of using when and unless to signal to human readers that the return value of the sexp is not important -- what is important are any side effects performed.